# VBA ADO connection in workbook to the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I have a workbook with some ADO connections to tables of data in the same workbook, and i have a problem when make the connection because Excel open my Workbook in another instance.

The string connection is:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';"
```

Somebody can help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want us to look at your connection whereas you say the problem is from the code that opens a workbook in its own instance of Excel? Shouldn't we rather look at that code?

Comment: What do you mean with _i have a problem when make the connection because Excel open my Workbook in another instance_?

Comment: I think he means he wants the workbook to open in the same instance of Excel but it opens another Excel instance. Sure I used to have issues with this type of thing in 2010.

Comment: here is the part of code:    'open connection
    Set sConnect = New ADODB.Connection
    sConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & DBPath & "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';"
    Conn.Open sConnect  <-- here Excel open a new instace of Excel whit my workbook, when que query ends close the workbook

Comment: Would you please add this to your post. Thanks! Please also try to explain your issue more concise. What I've got so far is that in your case `connection.open` triggers Excel to open another instance where the workbook will be openend again in read-only mode. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Take the following function

```
Function ConnectToXL(ByVal fileName As String)

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection

    If Dir(fileName) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Could not find file " & fileName
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim connectionString As String

    ' https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/
    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
               & fileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"

    conn.Open connectionString

    Set ConnectToXL = conn

End Function
```

And here is an example of a piece of code how to use it

```
   Dim xlCon As ADODB.Connection
    ' Connect to the workbook
    Set xlCon = ConnectToXL(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
```

And yes, the connection string is not much different to the one that was posted in the OP. `IMEX=1` should not do any harm resp. it is a safer way to retrieve data for mixed data columns.

Comment: Thaks, but dont work. When my code execute "Conn.Open sConnect" (open the connection to the workbook), Excel open a my workbook in another instance in mode read only. If i close the excel every time the connection is open a copy of the workbook opens.

Comment: So, what I was able te re-produce was the following. I started two Excel instances. I then opened in the second instance the file with the code and opened the ADODB connection. It will then open in the first instance the same file in read-only mode. No idea what is going on here. But it seems as long as you only have one instance of Excel running everything is fine.